# How to uninstall grub?

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader, efi, manjaro

I want to remove grub for another bootloader (i.e. OpenCore). I have some merits in doing so which I won't go into. So my question is how can I completely remove GRUB bootloader.

I can just remove the grub .efi files from my EFI partition but they will probably install themselves back if grub ever updates on my system. So can anyone suggest a way to completely remove grub.

My distro is `Manjaro`.
Package manager I usually use is `pacman`.

Comment: Remove it via your package manager, in your case pacman or pamac. Make sure to have a backup of your boot partition, in case you mess opencore up.